# How to use session variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.5, asp.net-4.5

After much research in Google, i haven't found a solution to my problem.

When i want to save a value to the Session variable, all is ok:

```
Session["idResult"] = youthID;
```

but when i want to get the value with the following line of code:

```
youthID = (int)Session["idResult"];
```

I get the error : Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the `<configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules>` section in the application configuration.

I've tried to adding it to the web.config : `EnableSessionState="True"`

and also :

```
<httpModules><add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>     </httpModules>
```

and many other possibilities but it's doesn't work

My default web.config is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Check if it is not set to false on the page...

Comment: what is your session state mode? Is it Inproc/State Server/ SQL?

Comment: Thomas, can you explain your answer please??

Comment: Create a fresh Asp.Net aplication with Visual Studio (have it?) from a template project and start it with the developer web server, which I believe is the default host. Add the lines to test Session state. Does it work then?

Comment: check your session state. set as **<sessionState mode="InProc">*

Comment: You said your "default" web.config... do you mean you have several config files? If so, check the last one because the last config file overrides any previous value.

Comment: @ManishSharma It's dosen't work...

Answer (score 0):

please you enable the session state in the section as well in config

```
 <system.web>
      <pages enableSessionState="true"> 
 </system.web>
```

Or  you can add this to the page

```
 <%@Page enableSessionState="true">
```

Comment: ASP.NET Session State Manager Service service is running?

Comment: Please make sure that you are not trying to reference
the session variable in one of your page's class constructor before the Session_Start function had been executed in the global.asax file.

Comment: i haven't the global.asax file, because it's not generated by visual 2012 when we creat a new ASP.NET Empty web site.
Can i had golbal.asax file in my existed project?
And if yes, which code i have to add in the Session_Star function??